# JavaScript function keyword appears to be preparsed when used declaratively?

Tags: javascript

I just discovered that the following code executes without error (Chrome):

```
console.log(fa);
function fa(){}
```

I was under the impression that:

```
function fa(){}
```

was identical to:

```
var fa = function(){};
```

My assumption had led me to believe that my code block above should have resulted in an error due to `fa` not having been declared before it was called. The second form however, when used in my code sample above, will produce an error because `fa` has not been defined yet when the first line runs.

Is there some documentation or information somewhere that covers the fact that the `function` keyword, when used declaratively, is preparsed, thus exposing said function in advance of the actual order of operation of the lines of code in a script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following

```
function fa(){}
```

is a *function declaration* which declares function `fa`, while

```
var fa = function(){};
```

declares a variable `fa` and initializes it with the result of a *function expression*. In JavaScript identifiers declared in a scope are **hoisted** to the top of the scope and hence are available throughout the scope. Initializers however are still executed in the place in the code where they appear.

Now, your *function expression* is executed (as any other initializer would be) at the point where it is placed in the code. Until the initializer is executed the variable holds `undefined` as its value.

*Function declaration*, on the other hand, is hoisted to the top of the scope as a whole together with the identifier under which the function is declared. Hence `fa` produced by the *function declaration* stores the right function object even when inspected above the place where the *function declaration* occurs.

```
fa1(); // valid
fa2(); // error, fa2 is undefined, not a function

function fa1() {}
var fa2 = function() {};

fa1(); // valid
fa2(); // valid
```

See [this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) for more on scoping and hoisting in JavaScript.

Comment: `function fa(){}` is a *function declaration* and is not a statement. The right hand side of `var fa = function(){};` is a *function expression*, not a "function definition expression". See the spec: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_13

Comment: I have used the terminology from "JavaScript the Definitive Guide", but after looking through the formal grammar I agree the term "function declaration statement" is misleading since it isn't a statement (see "SourceElement" in the grammar). I have updated terminology in my post to be in agreement with the specification (rather than a book). Note that this doesn't change the sense of my post. Thanks for spotting this!